# How to store List(list(value)) in cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, phantom-dsl

How to store `List(List(1,2,3,4),List(1,2,3,0))` values in one column in Cassandra table?

I have createed table with columns

list

Comment: Your should probably avoid that and serialze the list instead. Extract meaningful data before and insert and put that data as key

Comment: what language do you use to insert this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work automatically actually, except nested collection types will cause freezing.

Have you simply tried:

```
case class Record(id: UUID, nested: List[List[Int]])

abstract class MyTable extends Table[MyTable, Record] {
  object id extends Col[UUID] with PartitionKey
  object nested extends Col[List[List[Int]]
}
```

You will get a more funky Cassandra type when you do that, something of the kind `nested list<frozen<list<int>>>`, which means you cannot update the content of the nested lists, you can only update the entire column, but you should be able to do it.